# filter logs by hour or day in Suse

Tags: grep, logs, suse, sles

I'm new to Linux and I'm trying to figure out how to filter logs by day or hour in Suse.
I did some research and came across [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-log-files-location-and-how-do-i-view-logs-files/) and [this](http://logtail.blogspot.com/2007/04/how-to-search-logs-using-grep-part-1.html) and although it does say how to view the logs and found out that you can filter them with grep I do not know what is the regular expression or the attributes to make it work and I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267496/using-find-grep-to-search-files-between-specific-time-of-day) too but I don't understand it

Comment: OpenSuSE or SLES? Also, which version are you using?

Comment: @maxf SLES. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with SLES 12, SLES uses systemd and journald. Most services write their logs to the system journal, which you can view using `journalctl` (in most cases you need to be root). `journalctl` can filter using a variety of criteria, for you `--since=T` (T being e.g `-5m`) and `--unit=<servicename>` might prove useful. For more on this, look [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html). Apparently there's also a YaST module, but I haven't tried that yet.

Some services also write more detailed logs in /var/log, but filtering these by time depends on if and how the service writes timestamps to it's logfile, so without specifics I can't help you there.